# Conditional formatting based on percentage increases

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Cell C1 shows the same value as B1 with the difference between B1 and A1 in brackets. This is written with a formual in C1.

[image: img1]

I need to use conditional formatting on C1 to show if B1 is greater than A1 by 2% then turn to green, if B1 is less than A1 by 2% then red and if B1 is within the range of +/- 2% then turn amber.

I've tried conditional formatting on C1 as follow:
Selected the greater than option: =b1>(a1+(a1*0.02))
Selected less than option: =b1<(a1-(a1*0.02))
but this doesn't appear to work.

I'm stuck with the between the +/- 2% formual too.

Comment: B2 or B1? Please edit and clarify your question, you're using conflicting situations.

Comment: Sorry, amended now. All should have been B1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (I use European delimiter sign " **;** "):

Formula for values that are greater than 2%:

```
=((B1-A1)/A1)>2%
```

Formula for values that are less than 2%:

```
=((B1-A1)/A1)<-2%
```

The formula below is a combination of the two above. Since conditional formatting only apply changes with values that gives TRUE as a result, we need to create something that says TRUE when number is neither greater than 2% or less than 2%. So first part, the `OR(`, checks if either of the +2% or -2% is FALSE. If the statement is FALSE, that means that the values are between the +/- 2% range. So we take the `NOT(` to return a TRUE value.

```
=NOT(OR(((B1-A1)/A1)>2%;((B1-A1)/A1)<-2%))
```

Your condidtional formatting window should look something like this for cell C1 (which you can copy down by using format painter):

[image]

***Please notice one thing.***
If you enter your formula and it looks like the picture below with quotation mark signs ", then edit formula and remove the " signs at the beginning and the end of the formula.

[image]

Comment: A little bit off topic. In cell C1 you can have the following formula to automatically give you the value "103 (3): `=(B1/A1)*100 &" (" & ((B1/A1)*100)-100 & ")"`

Comment: Thank you! Glad it helped :)